# Save/restore pointers in member variables

Tags: javascript, pointers, web-worker

I have a data structure like (this is a gross simplification, it's not something that can be resolved by putting elements in a linked list collection):

```
null <-- [1] <==> [2] <==> [3] <==> [4] <==> [5] --> null
```

I need to pass, in a web worker postMessage() the sublist:

```
null <-- [2] <==> [3] <==> [4] --> null
```

So the easy way to do this is:

1. Save 2.prev, 4.next
2. set 2.prev & 4.next to null
3. postMessage() the truncated list.
4. set 2.prev & 4.next to their previous values.

I can do this with two lists, `listPrev` and `listNext`. Set the key as the variables 2 & 4 and the values are the pointer values. However, there are actually 6 different prev/next type member variables across different object types. So...

If this was C++ then I could store the address of the prev and next pointers as the key and have a single list of pointer addresses and values to set them to. Is there anything similar to this in javascript?

Comment: Why can't you just serialize this complex structure into a proper array that's just a sublist of your linked list? It'll take a little memory, but moving it to the web worker does that, anyway.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann A large number of our processing is not walking the list, it's calculating on an element where we may need to access the prev/next element. And sometimes insert an element after the one we are on. We tried doing all this using a ListIterator and it was a mess, both inefficient (finding the iteration position of an element) and complex (which leads to bugs).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've abstracted this into something like a LinkedList, I'd decorate it with something like a LinkedSublist that, on its own, stores the references of the first and last nodes, so you're not destructively changing the original list.

Comment: The problem is the code makes major use of the next/prev on given elements in cases where we're not walking the list. So we need that as part of the element.